# Configuring Lucene Index writer, controlling the segment formation (setRAMBufferSizeMB)

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, pylucene

How to set the parameter - setRAMBufferSizeMB? Is depending on the RAM size of the Machine? Or Size of Data that needs to be Indexed? Or any other parameter? could someone please suggest an approach for deciding the value of setRAMBufferSizeMB.

Answer (score 0):

So, what we have about this parameter in Lucene javadoc:

> Determines the amount of RAM that may be used for buffering added
> documents and deletions before they are flushed to the Directory.
> Generally for faster indexing performance it's best to flush by RAM
> usage instead of document count and use as large a RAM buffer as you
> can. When this is set, the writer will flush whenever buffered
> documents and deletions use this much RAM.
>
> The maximum RAM limit is inherently determined by the JVMs available
> memory. Yet, an IndexWriter session can consume a significantly larger
> amount of memory than the given RAM limit since this limit is just an
> indicator when to flush memory resident documents to the Directory.
> Flushes are likely happen concurrently while other threads adding
> documents to the writer. For application stability the available
> memory in the JVM should be significantly larger than the RAM buffer
> used for indexing.

By default, Lucene uses 16 Mb as this parameter (this is the indication to me, that you shouldn't have that much big parameter to have fine indexing speed). I would recommend you to tune this parameter by setting it let's say to 500 Mb and checking how well your system behave. If you will have crashes, you could try some smaller value like 200 Mb, etc. until your system will be stable.

Yes, as it stated in the javadoc, this parameter depends on the JVM heap, but for Python, I think it could allocate memory without any limit.